# Bind DropDownList from JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Need assistance with below JSON Response. I try to deserialize the

**JSON Response**

```
{  
"entities":[  
    {  
        "id":"/Severity/Critical",
        "Name":"Critical"
    },
    {  
        "id":"/Severity/High",
        "Name":"High"
    },
    {  
        "id":"/Severity/Low",
        "Name":"Low"
    },
    {  
        "id":"/Severity/Normal",
        "Name":"Normal"
    }
],
"paging":{  
    "from":4,
    "limit":100,
    "hasMore":false
}
}

var severity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Severity>(json);
```

**Error Message**

`` Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. ``

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: You should consider formatting your post to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the ErrorMessage is telling you, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject couldn't convert the JSON that you are using as input to an object. To avoid that, you could declare a specific class in which instance your JSON is going to be deserialized. Taking the input you shared, this class could look like this:

```
public class Severity
{

    [JsonProperty("entities")]
    public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("paging")]
    public Paging Paging { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id;

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name;
}

public class Paging
{
    [JsonProperty("from")]
    public int From { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("limit")]
    public int Limit { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("hasMore")]
    public bool HasMore { get; set; } 
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var severity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Severity>(json);
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you!